# Is it possible to mimic IQueryable with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Is it possible to mimic IQueryable with NHibernate?

I was looking at Nhibernate docs and for what i could tell, it always returns a List of objects, that have it's attributes indexed by a integer. Ok, perfect, that works.

But is there a way to retrieve objects like LINQ? With something like IQueryable?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other pointed out, there's a Linq provider for NHibernate 2.x which, while limited, handles simple queries (internally, it translates them to Criteria)

This is the correct download URL: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/2.1.2GA/NHibernate.Linq-2.1.2-GA-Bin.zip/download

The next version of NHibernate, 3.x (currently in development) has a built-in Linq provider, which is much more powerful, handling more complex queries including projections of several types.

You can download the binaries from [here](http://hornget.net/packages/orm/nhibernate/nhibernate-trunk), or compile from the trunk. It's pretty stable already.

Comment: Thank you all very much for you thoughts.

So I think it's a safe bet to use this provider to handle simple stuff. And later on i wont have to migrate code.
Thanks to all

Comment: Actually, it's been a while since your question. NHibernate 3.0 has been released and the new Linq provider works pretty well. Don't use the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Linq to NHibernate is available as part of NHibernate Contrib:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/files/

I have found that it is only usuable for simple queries.

Answer (score 0):

There is a linq provider for NHibernate.... not perfect, but handles most stuff